# Trying to assert role = Button when the using a dyanmic span id

Tags: selenium, xpath, dojo

I am trying to verify that there is a button on the page named `Select`. The Select button has a dynamic span id.

This is what firebug is showing me :

```
<span id="dijit_form_Button_18" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_18_label" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
```

This is my code that gives an Assertion Error !

```
Assert.assertEquals("button",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Select']")).getAttribute("role"));
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `//span[.='Select']` is the correct `xpath` for retrieving only the element you're interested in? What gets returned when you call `getAttribute("role")` on that element?

Comment: @mrfreester null is returned

Comment: It looks like your xpath is returning some other object. Can you provide more of the surrounding html? The attributes of this element don't seem to be enough to uniquely identify it, and you'll probably need to use some outer element as part of your selector. Something like an outer form or a neighboring field.

Comment: That makes sense. i'm kinda new to this and i know the proper syntax to use. I am simply trying to find the attribute of a dynamic id. I can more my code or html to suffice.